# My list view doesn't update when the user responds to an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a main activity with many fragments, one of which contains a list view, with adaptor `homeworkListAdapter`, this adapter does display any items initial in `homeworkItems`. My activity opens up another activity (`HomeworkAddActivity`, which gets a string from the user and puts it in an array `homeworkItems`, this all works as I have checked each step independently. However when I try to update the list view with this new item (using `.notifyDataSetChanged`) it doesn't update, I have been trying to fix this for 3-4 hours, please help.

Code

`MainActivity`

```
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> homeworkListAdapter;

public static ArrayList<String> homeworkItems; 

  ....

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
homeworkItems = new ArrayList<String>();

homeworkListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeworkItems);
....

 public static class HomeworkListViewFragment extends Fragment {

....

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_homework_listview, container, false);

        homeworkListView = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.homework_listview);

        homeworkListView.setAdapter(homeworkListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

`HomeworkAddActivity`

```
public class HomeworkAddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

....

public void buttonAddHomework(View v) {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_new_homework_name);
    String homeworkItem = (String) editText.getText().toString();
    if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(homeworkItem))) {
        //MainActivity.homeworkList.addItem(homeworkItem);
        MainActivity.homeworkItems.add(homeworkItem);
        MainActivity.homeworkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: try to recreate homeworkListAdapter totally in buttonAddHomework(). Sometimes notifyDataSetChanged() just wont work for unknown reason...

Comment: I have tried that (with different code), but I will try again, however I would much rather it was done more neatly/properly

Comment: I tried what you suggested again, it still failed to update the list

Comment: maybe `if (!(homeworkItem == null))` wont pass? did you checked it? Also try to use `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(homeworkItem))` - it cheks both for null and empty string.

Comment: I have tried changing the button text to the first item (`get(0)`) in `homeworkItems`, whilest commenting the `navigateUp`, and it worked fine, so all of that works.

Comment: And I have changed it to textutils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make a check like this:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(homeworkItem)) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ADDING AN ITEM!!!",Toast.LENGH_SHORT).show()
    homeworkItems.add(homeworkItem);
    homeworkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

just to be sure it passes the check. if it does (and you'll see the toast) then try

```
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(homeworkItem)) {
        homeworkItems.add(homeworkItem);
homeworkListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeworkItems);
homeworkListView.setAdapter(homeworkListAdapter);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
and the very last thing I assume your ListView has property android:height set to "wrap_content" - try to change it to "match_parent" :) It updates but you cant see it - try to scroll :)) And if this is it you should to fall back to `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: It still doesn't work, I have done both things (the first one shows the toast)

Comment: I have tried your update and it still didnt work, i will try your suggestion more thoroughly at some point

Comment: You see there is an issue with your ListView - it is not visible. That's the only thing that could be. Try to make it both width and height to match_parent and make sure you are not covering it by other layout or controls

Comment: Yeah, will have a look later. It is visible if i hard code items onCreate, however im guessing that is different to having wrap_content with dynamic data

Comment: Then AOS creates an empty ListView with wrap_content height it will be always invisible cuz atm of creation it takes zero height since there is nothing to show. It wont grow up when you adds items. Well, the invalidate() might help in this case but Im not sure

Comment: thankyou, my initial attempt didn't work as I didn't change all the fragments I had nested to match_parent, but it works now